# How to Stay in login status skip launcher activity?

Tags: android

I have a indexActivity , there is the edit text text for username and password and a login button. When user clicks on the login button , an asynchronous class will execute(There will be the authentication will done , by server call). If successfully authenticated homeActivity will start , using a intent.

In manifesto I set indexActivity as my launcher Activity.

I want to keep login status always , I mean After login , when user press back button app will minimize , when it starts again it may should go to the homeActivity.

I heard about sharedPreference but I don't how to use it in my case. I am a newbie to android ,I am in doubt about the condition.So please provide what the correct way to implement my requirement.

There is another doubt is that from the authentication result I am passing some objects with the intent and that are needed in the homeActivity. So what I can do?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Comment: @user3017713 have you solved it?

Comment: yes... thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated you should use SharedPreferences, something like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.put("login_data", the_api_token);
editor.commit();
```

That´s for saving the open session. Now you should check for this parameter when indexActivity starts on the onCreate method like this.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
if (prefs.getString("login_data", null) != null ) {
    // Start next activity
}
```

It should be great to set in the Manifest the `android:noHistory="true"` option on your indexActivity so when the user clicks the back button it never goes back to indexActivity, it will quit to the home screen.

**EDIT for the next doubt**

Every custom object that doesn't implement Parcelable can't be passed throught intents, so if you need to get some of your objects on other activities and you are planing to do it by intents you should implement that.

Here you have a little guide on how to do it.

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a session class, and in this write a code for sharedPreference  like this:

```
public class Session {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public Session(Context cntx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
    }

     
    public void setIslogin(boolean Islogin) {
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("Islogin", Islogin).commit();
        prefsCommit();
    }
    
    public boolean getIslogin() {
        boolean Islogin = prefs.getBoolean("Islogin", false);
        return Islogin;
    }
}
```

Now when you first time login successfully then just call `session.setIslogin(true)`.

And then in splash screen just mention like this or check like this:

```
   Session session = new Session(this);
        boolean TimeToLoad = session.getIslogin();
          if(TimeToLoad)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, AFTER_LOGIN_CLASS_NAME.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into `intent.putExtra("key","value")` and `intent.getExtra("key","value")` methods in the sending and receiving activities to send and receive values.

And it is an android feature that your application will open from the same activity you minimized. You don't have to write any code for it.
However, if your app is minimized for a long time, Android itself will kill your app.

Comment: Thank you for the response , but I think it is not what I asked

Comment: "There is another doubt is that from the authentication result I am passing some objects with the intent and that are needed in the homeActivity. So what I can do?" My answer reflects your question in quotes